# using curl in php for real post request to remote server

Tags: php, curl

I have to automate uploading values to a remote server by php script.

The interface accepts only POST variables - NO GET variables.

Interface documentation (for form field names) looks like:

```
iegUsername: your username
iegPassword: your password
iegImportFile: The UTF-8 encoded plain text import file. The file data may optionally be zipped.
```

This means i have to POST TWO VARIABLES and ONE FILE.
I'm new in Curl therefore i started in PHP with this:

```
// create curl resource
$request = curl_init();

// Array with the fields names and values
$postData = array(
'iegUsername' => 'myusername',
'iegPassword'  => 'mypassword',
'submit'    => 'ok'
);
//add file support with: 'file' => '@' . realpath('example.txt')

// set timeout if remote server is down
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);

// set remote target url
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, ""); //for testing post on current page

//Enable the post response.
//curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

$headers = ['Content-Type: multipart/form-data'];
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//The data to transfer with the response.
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// disable verification
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Actually i don't have added file support.

**My Problem**

In Browser dev tools i cannot see any POST only GET responses.

I need a real POST with data in it not a urled GET one...

Hopefully someone can give help.

Comment: You are not seeing the POST request because that request is done on server side, while you browser dev tools only sees client side requests.

Comment: hugh okay! how can i debug my variables?

Comment: With print_r(curl_getinfo($request)); i can't see the variables.

Answer (score 0):

okay, misunderstood of server side and client side. Thought a response back to my location should result in a post response within dev tools of browser, this is not correct.

POST works.